# canvas2pdf assign canvas object to context

Tags: canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

I need to capture the image of a webpage and save it as image/PDF. I am trying to implement canvas2pdf [canvas2pdf](https://github.com/joshua-gould/canvas2pdf). I get canvas in my javascript using html2canvas and then I am trying to generate a PDF. Does anyone know how to assign/add canvas to the Context in canvas2pdf. Is there any other script library that I can use (tried jsPDF [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) but it throws error - Blob is not a constructor). My code is as follows:

```
        html2canvas(document.getElementById(obj), {     
        logging:true,
        proxy:'app/qBlob/proxy.ashx',
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

             var ctx = new canvas2pdf.PDFContext(blobStream());

             //draw your canvas like you would normally
             // how to assign canvas to ctx??

             //convert your PDF to a Blob and save to file
             ctx.stream.on('finish', function () {
             var blob = ctx.stream.toBlob('application/pdf');
                saveAs(blob, 'example.pdf', true);
             });
             ctx.end();

            // jsPDF code
            // var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            // console.log(imgData);
            // var pdf = new jsPDF();
            // var marginLeft=20;
            // var marginRight=20;
            // pdf.addHTML(document.body);
            // pdf.save('example.pdf');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`Blob is not a constructor` is thrown with this line:

```
var ctx = new canvas2pdf.PDFContext(blobStream());
```

Change to this to avoid the error:

```
var stream = blobStream();
var ctx = new canvas2pdf.PdfContext(stream);
```

The code is an extract of the canvas2pdf demo page source here:

view-source:https://joshua-gould.github.io/canvas2pdf/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("barcodePrint"), { scale: 8 }).then(
      function (canvas) {
        let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        let doc = new jsPDF("l", "mm", [40, 20], true);

        doc.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, 0, 40, 18);
        let date = new Date().getTime();
        doc.save(date + ".pdf");
      }
);
```